# Missing application menus in most installed applications in Xubuntu 20.04 (also with a new desktop user)

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments, menu

For some reason, in most applications in my Xubuntu desktop, there is no main application menu (*File*, *View*, etc.).

Examples where I see the menu:

- Notepadqq
- Terminal

Examples where it is absent:

- OpenOffice/LibreOffice Writer/Calc
- Krita

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> does not help. What to do? I thought that might be some problem with the user profile, but in the new user profile I face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem. I notice that they re-appear if I use a different window manager such as Fluxbox or XMonad. But not strictly in XFCE itself.